Controlling a switch node with Geometry Proximity
I have this animated extrusion effect the faces of the extrusion have a different material then the sides and I want to be able to switch the facing material based on the animated geometry proximity, basically having the low points with a different material and high points with another I don't want it to be a smooth transition between the materials cause I don't think that's possible just a quick snap between the two.
Every time I plugged something into the switch I keep getting the red line, just can't seem to figure how I can control this switch with my current animation.




The Switch input should be a boolean, maybe try to put Greater Than node before it ? I'm not sure what you are expecting exactly.

If I understand your idea, you need two Set Material nodes one after the other, one per Flat Color, and not just one with a Switch node. Then you combine with an And Boolean Math node the Top output socket with the condition making the splitting between "low" points and "high" points (which seems to be missing as Lutzi commented).

the material data block is not a field, so you can't use a field (geometry dependent) value as the switch argument. (thinking about it, it seem weird that you could use seperated set materials based on field but not use it in a switch. anyway) you could alternatively use the set material index node.

Thanks for the comments I have to take another look at the set material index node, it was something played with earlier.
